# Custom List E-mail Column Auto Populate?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer

I am working with a new custom list and have one column named "E-mail" where the user entering info would have to manually find and enter the e-mail address for the person being entered.  I am wondering if there is a way to auto-populate the e-mail column with a users e-mail address based on a "Person or Group" column in the list?

Ex. IF  a Person or Group Column = Smith, John E  THEN
Auto-Populate (or Lookup?) E-mail Column = John.E.Smith@Banking.com

I don't have many tools at my disposal, just SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint Designer 2010.  If you need any further information let me know.  Any assistance on this is very much appreciated.  Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a person column, and under "Show Field" select `Work e-mail`.

Comment: Wow... I really should have opened my eyes... Thank you so much Erin L!

11 Minutes and I can mark as Answer :)